# How to use URL.createObjectURL inside a manifest v3 extension ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

My extension creates zip archive with images inside. And I used chrome.downloads.download to download my archive to device.

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(archiveBlob);

chrome.downloads.download({
  url,
  filename: `${archiveData.fileName}.zip`,
  saveAs: false
});
```

And also URL.createObjectURL required in my extension when I convert ArrayBuffer to Image

```
async bufferToImage(buffer: ArrayBuffer): Promise<InstanceType<typeof Image>> {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const blob = new Blob([buffer]);
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = objectURL;
    img.onload = () => res(img);
  });
}
```

How can I do it now in Manifest v3 ServiceWorker?

Comment: There's no way currently. You'll have to open a new tab with an html+js page of your extension where you'll run this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert **Blob** to **base64**.

If you want export image:

```js
/**
 * capture and download
 * 截图并下载
 */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {

  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, async (tabs) => {
    const tab = tabs[0];
    const image = await chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(tab.windowId, {
      format: "png",
    });

    chrome.downloads.download({
      url: image,
      filename: "1.png",
    })

  });
});
```

If you want export zip:

```js
import JSZip from "jszip";

/**
 * example: captureVisibleTab and export zip
 * 案例：截图并导出zip
 */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, async (tabs) => {
    const tab = tabs[0];

    // capture
    const image = await chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(tab.windowId, {
      format: "png",
    });

    // image base64 => blob
    const blob = await fetch(image).then((response) => response.blob());

    // zip image
    const zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file("insta-snap1.png", blob, { binary: true });
    const zipData = await zip.generateAsync({
      type: "base64",
    });

    // download zip with base64
    chrome.downloads.download({
      url: `data:application/octet-stream;base64,${zipData}`,
      filename: "test.zip",
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps me to solve my problem.